# custom view - rounding rectangle's corners drawn by lines

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, custom-view

I'm playing with custom views and I want to build a rounded rectangle using `path.lineTo()` and `path.arcTo()` methods.
So, the rectangle I want to get:

[image]

Normally I draw this with this block of code:

```
    RectF backReftf = new RectF();
    Path path = new Path();
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    float curve = (float) (0.1 *  height);
    RectF backReftf = new RectF();
    backReftf.left = 0;
    backReftf.top = 0;
    backReftf.right = width;
    backReftf.bottom = height;
    path.addRoundRect(backReftf, curve, curve, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

But I want to draw this with `path.lineTo()` and `path.arcTo()`.

According to Docs about `arcTo()`:

> Append the specified arc to the path as a new contour. If the start of the path is different from the path's current last point, then an automatic lineTo() is added to connect the current contour to the start of the arc. However, if the path is empty, then we call moveTo() with the first point of the arc.

So theoretically my arc should start there, where line ends, so if I drew a line (left side of rectangle):

```
    float curve = (float) (0.1 *  height);
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(0, height - curve);
```

then my arc should start from this point (0, height - curve), but where do I pass those arguments when `arcTo()` has following parameters:  `arcTo (float left, 
              float top, 
                float right, 
                float bottom, 
                float startAngle, 
                float sweepAngle, 
                boolean forceMoveTo)`
?

Plus how do I calculate in this case `startAngle` and `sweepAngle`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When drawing an arc, you need to specify the full bounding box for that arc, and the start and sweep angle. I try to see them visually, like so:

[image: arcTo angles]

E.g. when going clock wise, the start angle is positioned 180degrees from the origin. And from the startAngle, if you sweep 90 degrees clock wise, you'll end up at the desired end position.

Take note where the origin, startAngle and sweepAngle are in this graphic.
In kotlin, it can look something like this:

```
// Given some radius, viewWidth and viewHeight
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        path.apply {
            moveTo(radius, 0F)
            lineTo(viewWidth - radius, 0F)
            arcTo(viewWidth - 2 * radius, 0F, viewWidth, 2 * radius, -90F, 90F, false)
            lineTo(viewWidth, radius)
            arcTo(viewWidth - 2 * radius, viewHeight - 2 * radius, viewWidth, viewHeight, 0F, 90F, false)
            lineTo(radius, viewHeight)
            arcTo(0F, viewHeight - 2 * radius, 2 * radius, viewHeight, 90F, 90F, false)
            lineTo(0F, radius)
            arcTo(0F, 0F, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180F, 90F, false)
        }

        canvas?.drawPath(path, linePaint)
    }
```

And the result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Well described, thank you! I'll also leave link to Microsoft's docs where arcs are also explained, but to me you did it better ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/arcs

Comment: Your code only works in api 21 and above. It would be more useful if you placed the version of code that works in all api's.

Comment: How to draw only 2 lines with arc between them using the given answer ? Please help @Entreco

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that the rect is supposed to surround a piece of arc that is drawn, not the potential 360 degrees arc.